# how do i create slider on Wix website builder?

Tags: image, web, slider, gallery, velo

I want to create slider on Wix that will be rotation images and displaying them by sliding from left to right.

I tried Wix pro gallery but doesn't work the way I expected.
kindly help me to figure out how I can make it work out and what app to use that will make it look like I want and I can be proud off.